# char array outputting as weird symbols

Tags: c++, arrays

So Ive been learning about classes, and in my main function when I run it, it shows character array members incorrectly.

main program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "account.h"
#include "account.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main(){

    char num [] = "2435457";
    char name [] = "BOB JOE";
    account bob(10000, num, name );
    bob.show_account();
    cout << num; // this should output correctly, but shows the '♦'
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
ACCOUNT INFO:
    Account holder :
    Account number :♦
    Balance :10000
♦
```

Whats weird is that using `cout<<` directly on the char array `num` shows the '♦'.
When I copy the `char num [] = "2435457"` into a new program like:

```
#include <iostream>    //including all the same headers does not affect
#include "account.h"   //the output
#include "account.cpp" 
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char num [] = "2435457";
    cout << num;
    return 0;
}
```

It works correctly.
EDITED :
Here is the header "account.h"

```
#ifndef BANK_H_
#define BANK_H_
using namespace std;

class account {
    static const int NMAX = 20, AMAX = 10;
    private:
        double balance;
        char account_number [AMAX];
        char account_holder [NMAX];
    public:
        account(double BAL, char acct [], char name []);
        void show_account();
        void deposit(double money);
        void withdrawl(double money);
};
#endif
```

And "account.cpp"

```
#include "account.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

account::account(double BAL, char acct[], char name[]){
    strcpy(name, account_holder);
    strcpy(acct, account_number);
    balance = BAL;
}

void account::show_account(){
    cout << "ACCOUNT INFO :"<<endl;
    cout << "\tAccount holder :";print(account_holder);
    cout << "\n\tAccount number :";print(account_number);
    cout << "\n\tBalance :"<<balance<<endl; 
}

void account::deposit(double money){
    balance += money;
} 

void account::withdrawl(double money){
    balance -= money;
}
```

Comment: Evidently, the code you haven't shown (the two-line difference between the two `main` functions) is the culprit. Please show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the emphasis on complete.

Comment: Please show the definition of `account`, I'm guessing that there's something wrong in the constructor. Also just a note, you usually shouldn't `#include` .cpp files.

Comment: Also it is a bad practice to using namespaces. Just call functions with namespace prefixes like std::cout << "Hello World";

Comment: @chris Yup, never mind... Comes with the literal.

Comment: Read over `strcpy` again. You could avoid this problem by using `std::string`.

Comment: I'm choosing to use a char array, telling me to use std::string does not explain why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Senhor, that's irrelevant to the question, using the whole std namespace may be bad practice, but its not whats causing the issue, please stay on topic.

Comment: @Jordan it's good advice to use the right tool for the job. You're basically asking "How do I use a screwdriver handle to hammer in a nail? Oh, and I didn't read the manual that came with the screwdriver"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the constructor like I thought.

```
account::account(double BAL, char acct[], char name[]){
    strcpy(name, account_holder);
    strcpy(acct, account_number);
    balance = BAL;
}
```

`strcpy`'s [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) says:

```
char* strcpy( char* dest, const char* src );
```

so you got the 2 parameters switched, you're copying from the uninitialized member array into your char pointer. Since the member array is uninitialized at that point reading from it is undefined behavior. You should switch them:

```
account::account(double BAL, char acct[], char name[]){
    strcpy(account_holder, name);
    strcpy(account_number, acct);
    balance = BAL;
}
```